If $A \times B$ is closed in $(X \times Y, d)$, show that $A$ is closed in $X$ and $B$ is closed in $Y$, where A and B are nonempty subsets of X and Y
I am studying some basic topology online, and saw a question:
Let $(X, d_X)$ and $(Y, d_Y)$ be metric spaces. Define
$$
    d((x_{1}, y_{1}), (x_{2}, y_{2})) =  \max\{ d_{X}(x_{1}, x_{2}), d_{Y}(y_{1}, y_{2}) \}, \quad (x_{i}, y_{i}) \in X \times Y, \, i = 1, 2
$$
is a well-defined metric on $X \times Y$, making $(X \times Y, d)$ a metric space called the product space of $X$ and $Y$.
If $ $ $\emptyset \neq A \subset X$, $\emptyset \neq B \subset Y$ are such that $A \times B$ is closed in $(X \times Y, d)$, show that $A$ is closed in $X$ and $B$ is closed in $Y$.
I have some idea of using the fact that $X \times Y - A \times B$ is open, and use this to prove $X - A$ and $Y - B$ are open in $X$ and $Y$ respectively. I'm not sure whether my idea is correct or not.
Also,

For the same metric spaces, I'm considering proving the continuity of the mapping $f: X\times Y$ $->$ $X$, by proving $f$ is continuous at
every point in $X\times Y$ using the defined metric above.

I'm not sure if it is feasible or not. Could anyone give your own insights or thoughts?
Thank you so much in advance!

Show directly that they are closed using the sequence property

Since we are dealing with metric spaces, we will use the definition of a closed set to be a set that contains its limit points. We will show that $A$ is closed and the fact that $B$ is closed can be shown similarly.
Let $p\in X$ be a limit point of $A$. Then for any $\epsilon\gt 0$, we know that $B_{\epsilon}(p)=\{x: d_X(x,p)\lt\epsilon\}$ contains a point of $A$.
Since $B\ne\emptyset$, there exists $b\in B$ and I claim that $(p,b)$ is a limit point of $A\times B$.
For any $a\in A$, $$d((a,b), d(p,b))=\text{ max($d_X(a,p), d_Y(b,b)$)}=d_X(a,p)$$ because $d_Y(b,b)=0$
Since $p$ is a limit point for $A$, for any $\epsilon\gt 0$, there exists $a\in A$ such that $d_X(a,p)\lt\epsilon$
But $d((a,b),(p,b))=d_X(a,p)$ so $(a,b)\in B_{\epsilon}((p,b))$.
Therefore, $(p,b)$ is a limit point of $A\times B$ and since $A\times B$ is closed, it contains its limit points.
Therefore, $(p,b)\in A\times B$ so $p\in A$.
Since the same argument can be applied to all limit points of $A$, $A$ is closed.

Thank you for your insights! It is clear enough for me.
